# VSTS - Setting $(Rev:.r ) starting value

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We are moving from TeamCity to VSTS for builds and one of the features of TeamCity we use is the build counter associated to a build definition that increments on every build as a part of our version number, e.g.

1.2.3.buildcounter

In VSTS I see I can use the $(Rev:.r) build property to get the build counter paradigm working, but I would like to be able to seed it at a given value so when we cut over from TeamCity we are sequentially at the next version.

Answer (score 2):

It seems there is an API to do just that. Have a look at this part of the documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/build/definitions/update%20counter%20seed?view=vsts-rest-4.1

And for posteriority:

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/definitions/{definitionId}?counterId={counterId}&newSeed={newSeed}&resetValue={resetValue}&api-version=4.1
```

Comment: Now question is where to find "counter ID"

Answer (score 1):

Although I was not able to find the counter id to use Marc's suggestion, I found Eddie Chen's answer to this other question to be a great workaround.

[How to manually start $(Rev:r) counter from specific number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52663175/how-to-manually-start-revr-counter-from-specific-number?answertab=votes#answer-52735197)

Comment: The linked answer worked perfectly, thanks. You may want to reference what was done at that linked answer, for posterity.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. If possible from a process perspective, just bump the version number to 1.2.4 and start fresh.